# GridView.Columns[index].HeaderText Throws "Index was out of range" Error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

```
    gvOff.DataSource = o.ViewData(dCity.SelectedValue);
    gvOff.DataBind();
    gvOff.Columns[0].HeaderText = "ZZZZZZZZ";
    gvOff.Columns[1].HeaderText = "YYYYYYYY";
    gvOff.Columns[2].HeaderText = "XXXXXXXX";
```

**Header count is correct.**

**AutoGenerateColumns: Flase/True ( i tried both)**

**If i remove the gvOff.Columns[index].HeaderText portions, GridView works fine, but when i put the gvOff.Columns[0].HeaderText, i get the exceptional error.**

Can you please help, i couldn't solve it. If you need further info, inform me.

---

EDITED:

Hold on! I commented the HeaderText portion and tested

int i = gvOffer.Columns.Count;

I found count is 0 eventhough the columns print out with DataBind()... Why?

NOTE: AutoColumn in this case is set to true. I guess i will have to edit the column
names from DataTable.

Comment: are you sure that datasource is valid and column count is > 0?

Comment: Hold on! I commented the HeaderText portion and tested:  int i = gvOffer.Columns.Count; I found count is 0 eventhough the columns print out with DataBind()... Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved .... I just changed column name using SQL Query alias then this reflected in my application. For example:

```
SELECT orderID AS [XXXXX], name AS [YYYYY] FROM TableName
```